# What is the proper way to handle React state and props

Tags: reactjs, render

I've been using React for a while, and I've tried many different approaches to do this, they all have their advantages and disadvantages so I'd like to clarify which one is the way to go.

So I have this example scenario: 
- A (smart) parent component, listening to a flux store
- A (dumb?) child component being rendered by the parent component above only rendering a view and having some "small internal logic", and by that I mean, some logic that doesn't make sense to be handled by an external action, like onChange events that update its input value, for example.

Should I only pass whatever I wanna pass to the child component as props, and don't mess with its state. So whatever small logic I need to do I update its props directly (even tho I know it's not recommended to update props directly)?

Or

I pass whatever props I wanna pass to the child component and then "get them" in the getInitialState, do that small logic using its now state variables?

The problem with the second approach is that when I actually send an action from the child component, and the parent component listens to the stores results and gets updated, and I have a hard time re rendering the child component now, unless I change its key value, which I also think it shouldn't be done this way.

And the first approach, even tho I'm changing props, which, like I said, I don't think it's also the best thing to do this, I don't have a problem re rendering the child component after sending an action that updates the store that the parent component is listening to.

Probably there are other ways to do it, and for sure a better way. And that is what I'd like to see. Let me know if the question is confusing and I'll try explaining in some other way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only set state from the main (parent) component. All children components should be "dumb" components. If you need to manipulate state from a child component...have a function in the parent component that modifies the state needed...then pass that function as a prop to the child. When the action needed to update the state in the child is completed, call the function passed in as a prop which will call it in the parent component and will update state accordingly.

Below is just some boilerplate code to give you an idea as to what I'm talking about.

Example child component:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Child extends Component {

        edit = () => {
            var state = "string";
            this.props.edit(state);
        }

handleChange = (evt) => {
this.props.inputChange(evt.target.value);

        render() {
            return (
                <button type="button" onClick={this.props.edit}>Click Me!</button>
<input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Child;
```

Example parent component :

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import Child from './Child';

    class Parent extends Component {

        edit = (val) => {
            this.setState({data: val})
        }

inputChange = (val) => {
  this.setState ({input: val});
}

        render() {
            return (
                <Child edit={this.edit} inputChange={this.inputChange}>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Parent;
```

Comment: you say that even if the child had an input with an onChange event?

Comment: @AndréMoretzsohndeCastro not sure what you're asking...I edited my response to add an onChange event. Let me know if this answers your question

Comment: Thanks @erichardson30. Yeah, that answers my question. But I guess you forgot to pass the value from the parent back to the child element...

Comment: @AndréMoretzsohndeCastro I'm not sure what value you're talking about. But if the answer solved your issue then please mark it as correct